# Trying to get some code in my PHP Form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

First I want to say that I'm not that experienced with PHP or programming
Hello I'm trying to get some simple php code in my PHP  form.

This is my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Product/product_form'); ?>" method="post">


  <h2> Cadeau aanbieden</h2>

    <table class="aanbieding-cadeau">
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_naam', 'name'=>'product_naam', 'placeholder' => '1. Naam van het cadeau', 'size'=>25));?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo($selectField);?></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'placeholder' => '3.Kies een stad', 'size'=>25));?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <h4>Upload foto</h4>
       <?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'file','id'=>'product_foto', 'name'=>'product_foto', 'placeholder' => '3.Upload foto', 'size'=>25));?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo form_textarea(array('type'=>'textarea','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'placeholder' => '5. Vertel iets over dit cadeau..', 'size'=>25));?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadeau aanbieden!</button>
     </td>
    </tr>     
  </table>
</form>
```

This is the code that I want in my form:

```
<?php
    echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
    echo form_open_multipart();
    echo form_upload('file');
    echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
    echo form_close();
    ?>
```

I want the code above in this table row :

```
 <tr>

  <td>
    <h4>Upload foto</h4>
   <?php echo form_input(array('type'=>'file','id'=>'product_foto', 'name'=>'product_foto', 'placeholder' => '3.Upload foto', 'size'=>25));?></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: can you be more precise with your problem ?

Comment: how can i get this code: <?php
    echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');
    echo form_open_multipart();
    echo form_upload('file');
    echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
    echo form_close();
    ?>      in that table row?

Comment: The form parts go in your form. Look up forms in the documentation